# Linked SharePoint list only displays 30 records in Access

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have about 10 SharePoint lists that are linked to my access database. Most of the lists perform correctly, but one only shows 30 records (there are about 17k records). I suspect it has to do with view settings but I can't figure out what to change to get it to display all items like the other lists. Thanks.

***UPDATE:*** I had caching set to never cache, when I turned caching back on with the clear cache on close it it started working

Comment: This question could potentially benefit from knowing which version of SharePoint and which version of MSAccess you are using.

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2013 and Access 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

17k is well above the [List View Threshold](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59#__overview).  If you are not getting List View Threshold errors, it is likely that someone has already configured [list view filtering](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-filtering-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4) to solve the list view threshold problem.  With this large of a list, you are going to run into all sorts of issues with views and querying.

You will likely need to do some kind of query against your linked table to see the rows you are looking for, and you probably won't be able to view all 17,000 rows at once.  See [this article for dealing with List View Threshold issues in Access-to-SharePoint linked tables](http://nellisconsultingllc.com/manage-large-sharepoint-lists-with-microsoft-access-sharepoint-tip/).

Comment: Changing the cache setting from "never cache" to "clear cache on close" fixed the problem

Comment: You should officially post that as an answer band mark it as the accepted correct answer so that it is preserved for future users affected by the same problem.